# Eliminate/Turn off volume of Spoken word of Music VLC

Tags: windows-10, vlc-media-player

So I've got a quit nice and big (for my standards at least :P) music library on my PC. Is there some way on VLC to turn off spoken words (i.e. turn off the volume of frequency at which words are spoken) so that only background Music plays?

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there some way in VLC to turn off spoken words?

You could try the "Simple Karaoke filter":

1. "Tools" > "Preferences".
2. Select "All" in the "Show settings" section.

   [image]
3. Select "Filter" in the "Audio" subtree.
4. Enable "Simple Karaoke filter" in the "Filters" selection.

   [image]
5. Click "Save".
6. Restart VLC.

Comment: The filter isnt really nice, but thanks for the effort anyways. Gonna leave it unanswered though, this filter blocks music too :(

Comment: hi, this works well for me!  thanks